# How to use join clause

Tags: sql

```
SELECT   c.LastName, 
         c.FirstName, 
         i.InvoiceId, 
         i.CustomerId, 
         i.InvoiceDate, 
         i.BillingCity,
         i.total  
FROM     invoices i 
INNER JOIN customers c ON i.CustomerId=c.CustomerId
WHERE BillingCity LIKE 'P%' OR 'S%'
```

I am trying to find records from the cities that start with P and S. When I run this query, It only returns the cities with P.

Comment: BillingCity LIKE 'P%' OR  BillingCity LIKE 'S%'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your WHERE clause is incorrect.  You can't say "LIKE this OR that".  You need two different LIKE expressions, joined with an OR.

```
WHERE 
    BillingCity LIKE 'P%'
    OR 
    BillingCity LIKE 'S%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT   c.LastName, 
         c.FirstName, 
         i.InvoiceId, 
         i.CustomerId, 
         i.InvoiceDate, 
         i.BillingCity,
         i.total  
FROM     invoices i 
INNER JOIN customers c 
    ON i.CustomerId=c.CustomerId
WHERE (i.BillingCity LIKE 'P%' OR i.BillingCity LIKE 'S%')
```